# if size()==0 is enough when checking if a list is empty

Tags: apex

I am practicing out Apex as a beginner and have a question. I have apex such as the one below to insert a record when a List is empty. I am using `if(apps.size()==0{` If i'm looking to see if a list is empty is it best to do  `if(apps.size() == 0)` or `size()==0` OR `(apps.isEmpty())` OR `if(app = null)`  ? Or a combination?

Example code snippet below:

```
if (Account.application_c ! = null){
    List<applicant> apps =[select id, status from applicant where applicationID = :Account.application_c];

if(apps.size()==0{

Applicant applicant = new Applicant{
Applicationid=account.application_c,
Status ='new');

insert applicant;}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Apex! Have you looked at these questions & answers? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/154955/81648 || https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/153157/81648

Comment: or https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77173/list-isempty-vs-list-size-0-vs-list-null/77200 ?

Comment: ^^^ even better!

Answer (score 2):

Checking `size()` or `isEmpty()` is usually good enough, and both are equally acceptable in my eyes.

If your list (or set, or map) is defined within the method you're using it in, then it's pretty easy to make sure that it's never null (empty and null are two different things).

If you're passing a collection into a method as a parameter though, it then makes sense to check to make sure that it isn't null first (and if you're doing a null check, it should always be the first thing you check).

Taking your example, the pattern I usually use is something closer to

```java
// Declaring and initializing the list outside of any if() blocks means
//   we know it will never be null (and thus do not need to do any null checking)
List<Applicant__c> applicantList = new List<Applicant__c>();

// isBlank() and isNotBlank() are generally useful
// They detect null strings as well as empty strings (i.e. '')
if(String.isNotBlank(Account.application__c)){
    // A SOQL query will never return a null result
    // If you don't get an exception, then the worst you'll get is an empty list
    applicantList = [SELECT id, status FROM Applicant__c WHERE applicationID = :Account.application__c];
}

// I've structured the code in such a way that no matter what path we take, we
//   never end up with a null list (so no null check required).
// I prefer isEmpty() because it returns a boolean result.
// That means it can be used directly in an if() statement
if(applicantList.isEmpty()){
    // If you don't need to use this new record elsewhere, you can save a little
    //   typing by adding it directly to your list
    applicantList.add(new Applicant__c(
        ApplicationId__c = Account.Application__c
    ));
}

// If you're not sure if you will have an existing record or create a new one, then
//   'upsert' is your friend
// Salesforce is kind enough to handle DML on empty lists as a no-op
//  (i.e. you don't need to check if a list is empty before performing
//   DML)
upsert applicantList;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Derek F! I appreciate you for going through the example and listing what is best practice/useful. I am trying to learn the differences and when best to use the empty vs size null indicators. I have a basic question to ask. is it preferable to do applicantList.add(new Applicant__c (see this is your example) over Applicant applicantList = new ApplicationList for a specific reason?

Comment: @DigitalWoman Honestly, there's no real advantage in adding a new instance directly to a list compared to assigning it to a variable and then adding it to a list. It's mostly a code-style thing. To an extent, being lazy as a programmer is a plus. In this case specifically, I tried to be "lazy" by reducing the amount of typing that I needed to do. The generally accepted maxim is "the more you type, the more chances you have to make a mistake".